# onStartCommand is calling only once in service android?

Tags: android, android-service

i have a simple service need to run in background.below is the code for the service.i want to run the code in onStartCommand repeatedly simply for test purpose i displayed toast.but Toast also calling only once

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;




/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions and extra parameters.
 */
public class WiFiCheck extends Service {




    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.


        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    /**
     * Handle action Foo in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionFoo(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Foo
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Handle action Baz in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionBaz(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Baz
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

but onStartCommand is calling only once getting toast only once.

i used

```
return START_STICKY;
```

starting service as below

```
        startService(new Intent(this, WiFiCheck.class));
```

but still no use.any help

Answer (score 1):

Toast will be twice and more called if you start again service

e.g.

```
startService(new Intent(this, WiFiCheck.class));
startService(new Intent(this, WiFiCheck.class));
```

`new Intent` is an intent which is in `onStartCommand(Intent intent`

Comment: why to start twice ..services meant for contentious operations..want to start it once need to get toast again and again until i stop the service

Comment: `services meant for contentious operations` only of it is *foreground*. try out such way and make toast in a loop e.g.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Call `StartService` as much times as you want the toast to show up.

**About returning START_STICKY(Why doesn't returning START_STICKY show your toast twice?)**

Returning `START_STICKY` at the end of `onStartCommand()` method lets your service start again(`onStartCommand()`  is called again) when your service is **KILLED**(by some reasons like system resource depletion). So there is **no relevence** between `return START_STICKY;` and your goal.

**Solution to reach your goal**

Like the Kalyzunyu's answer, just call `StartService()` twice to show your toast twice. **It does not instantiate your Service twice,** but calls your `onStartService()` twice. So be free to call it again.

Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

**Or** if you want to show the toast every 10 seconds until it is stopped try this.

```
public class WiFiCheck extends Service
{

    private Thread thread;




    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
        thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    while(true)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(WiFiCheck.this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep((long)10000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {}
                    }


                }
            });
            thread.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    /**
     * Handle action Foo in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionFoo(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Foo
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Handle action Baz in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionBaz(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Baz
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        thread.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

This code below is equivalant to above.

In Activity

```
    new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
             @Override
             public void run()
             {
                   while(!isInterrupted()){
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WiFiCheck.class)); 
                       Thread.sleep(10000L);  
                   }
             }
        }).start();
```

Equivalent code #2:

```
public class WiFiCheck extends IntentService
{
  public WiFiCheck() {
     super("WiFiCheck");
 }
 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
 {
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
      return START_STICKY;

        }
 }
```

To add words, starting a service does **not** mean it is **repeatedly** called by the system, but rather it can **live longer without UI.** Actually its context is continued until you manually call `stopSelf()` or any component calls `stopService()` on your service.

Comment: Could you please post some comment here about why this was downvoted? I don't want to make the mistake again and want to improve my post. If it is an exact duplicate of @V.Kalyuzhnyu's answer, (I am so sorry V.Kalyuzhnyu!) I would rather suggest edit to him. Or if my answer is totally wrong what point(If both answers are wrong, sorry moderators, I just upvoted V.Kalyuzhnyu's and can't undo it, though it seems that only mine is wrong)?

Comment: @GajuKollur Nope.. I meant that you should call StartService twice, but returning Start_sticky is irrelevant.

Comment: @GajuKollur For example, any time you call StartService() the toast will show up. Also the toast will show up when you force-stop it after your service had returned START_STICKY, because the system will automatically restart your service.

Comment: @GajuKollur In this case, two conditions call your onStartCommand: 1. Whenever you call startService. 2. You returned START_STICKY in onStartCommand, and your service was crashed or killed -> When thesystem restarts your service.

Comment: @GajuKollur If you meant you wanted to show toast consistently try my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

YES.., You just have to return `START_STICKY` as `KYHSGeekCode` suggested. It was down voted, but it is correct answer. So i up voted it back. Thank you

Comment: just take care if you are trying it on android 8.0 or above then use startforeground

Comment: even after using START_STICKY onstartCommand calling only once ..i am testing on kitkat

Comment: @GajuKollur Ok I read yours. Bu I think you misunderstood my answer. Returning START_STICK is irrelevant.....

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode Dear down voter will you please tell me how returning START_STICKY is irrelevant? You are misusing the right of down vote

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode, He wants to run onStartCommand repeatedly.., For which START_STICKY is the only way.. I do not see anything wrong in my answer

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode, Please suggest any clues if you can over my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953562/run-service-again-but-once-its-current-execution-is-finished

Comment: @GajuKollur, import android.app.IntentService;  is you problem.  What intentservice required thing doing in your service...?? It must not be there....

Comment: @sandhyasasane To see if I had downvoted, visit here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down . Neither did i downvoted nor upvoted.

Comment: @sandhyasasane And not "must not", but rather "need not" that import statement.