# Run service again but Once its current execution is finished

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I will try to keep it short and simple. I have a `foreground service A` with `broadcast receiver`. Some times it calls `Service B` twice.

---

I want `service B` to finish its execution first and if another request comes to run it again, it should remain awaiting until earlier execution finish. Thats why i have created Service B as `IntentService`. But as call log is still not updated, i am sleeping service B for 2 seconds.

---

But when i implemented runnable in IntentService..., It left its original behaviour and if another request comes, both requests are running Service B concurrently.

---

My Service Broadcast receiver :

```
Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "CALL ENDS HERE...");
Intent SendSMS = new Intent(context, SendSMS.class);
startService(SendSMS);
```

---

My IntentService :

```
    public class SendSMS extends IntentService
    {
    public Boolean IsRunning = false;

    public SendSMS()
    {
    super("SendSMS");
    Log.d("SendSMS : ", "\nOnCreate...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                if(IsRunning == false)
                {
                    IsRunning = true;
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    // perform operations here...
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
    }
```

---

My operations should be performed twice , But after first is finished with sleep of 2 seconds. Any help will be appreciated. Thanking you in advanced

Comment: I finally got it. You shouldn't use IntentService as it will automatically call stopSelf after you returned from onHandleIntent.

Comment: Subclass Service instead.

Comment: I mean that isrunning var is evaporated.

Answer (score 1):

My app targets api level 26 from api 17. But as in and above Oreo it is not allowed to implement static receivers. ( There are few intent actions like `BOOT_COMPLETED` are still accepted. But I wanted to implement `PHONE_STATE`. As per documentation i have implemented it in a foreground service. as below :

---

Runtime Receiver in Foreground Service :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mCallBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "INCOMING CALL...");
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            {
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "CALL ENDS HERE...");
                Intent Dispatcher = new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class);
                startService(Dispatcher);
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
            {
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "ACTIVE CALL GOING ON...");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

here you can see, i am calling my `CatchNumbers`. YES I AM CALLING ONCE, BUT AS ONLY ON IN ANDROID 5.0 AND 5.1 GOOGLE BUG, IT TRIGGERS `ALL_STATES` TWICE TWICE. `Hence was the above question Posted here` that how to disallow two concurrent threads running the same service..!!

---

Within `CatchNumbers` :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                Log.d("CatchNumbers : ", "\nDispatched Call ...");

                Intent SendSMS = new Intent(CatchNumbers.this, SendSMS.class);
                startService(SendSMS);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Log.d("CatchNumbers : ", "Thread : InterruptedException Error in service...\n");
                Log.e("CatchNumbers : ", "Exception is : ", e);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Before heading concurrent calls to same `SendSMS` service, here within runnable sleep of 2 seconds and then only dispatch it to run IntentService worker thread...

---

> Now as Intent Service does not allow to run multiple instances... Other request remains awaiting until first `SendSMS` execution gets completes. Now, Dear XY LOVER.., As android 5.0 and 5.1 triggers twice the same event it would have been problematic to call any service.., which was causing data loss... So decided to get it from CALL_LOG instead. Once call state goes IDLE. Again same problem of concurrent calls to that intent service so solved it like this.  I also tried implementing runnable in Intent service but because of it Intent service lost its property of keeping next request in waiting until current execution ends. And Both of requests were running IntentService Concurrently causing data loss

---

Now My Intent Service is not having Runnable method.

Comment: so you have `BroadcastReceiver` triggered by `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` action, and it is called twice, right? so, now imagine a leaking roof in your house, and when raining the water damages your rooms, what you do in such case? do you really build a system of channels draining your rooms from water or simply fix the hole in the roof? your solution is nothing but a bad workaround and if you spent 5 minutes on googling you would find [this](https://www.skoumal.com/en/android-duplicated-phone-state-broadcast-on-lollipop/) simple solution, do you know what is `XY problem` now?

Comment: @pskink, Well..., I really appreciate it. I am studying it... Lets see.. Yes it is helpful for me and if its really standard and if it is documented in google android developers... I would then request you to write it as answer and will accept it. Upon i find it helpful.., Going through it.

Comment: @pskink,  Some points from that link are : 1) very poorly documented by google. 2) subscription as general object, because it is long for Android 5.0 and int for Android 5.1. 3) Android 6 subscription extra is no longer attached 4) Personally I have found google documentation very poor even  for api level 26 they shows you restrictions on service and broadcast but does not depict how to register it within service runtime. They have just one line context.register. In this case too  how to implement it already have thousands of cases for making it supportive for 4.1 upto Android P